# Camel Kafka Connector - Azure Blob Storage Source Connectors Using SAS Token

Tags: apache-camel

We are implementing Camel Kafka Connector - Azure Storage Blob source to download files form AZ Blob storage container.

We found that for authentication the connector requires AccessKey, where AccessKey has full access of the storage account and we don't want got with accesskey as there are no restrictions.

https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/next/reference/connectors/camel-azure-storage-blob-source-kafka-source-connector.html

We tried to use SAS Token for authentication and got error in HMAC Encryption, is it possible to use SAS Token instead of AccessKey.

```
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:80) ~[camel-quartz-3.18.2.jar:3.18.2]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:837) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:589) ~[na:na]
    at com.azure.storage.common.implementation.StorageImplUtils.computeHMac256(StorageImplUtils.java:252) ~[azure-storage-common-12.15.2.jar:12.15.2]
    at com.azure.storage.common.StorageSharedKeyCredential.generateAuthorizationHeader(StorageSharedKeyCredential.java:149) ~[azure-storage-common-12.15.2.jar:12.15.2]
    at com.azure.storage.common.policy.StorageSharedKeyCredentialPolicy.process(StorageSharedKeyCredentialPolicy.java:38) ~[azure-storage-common-12.15.2.jar:12.15.2]
```

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the error messages instead of adding them as comments.